# Bypass Approval in powershell foreach loop

Tags: powershell

I have a `foreach` loop in powershell to delete all deleted sites that are already in recycle bin of SharePoint. But when I run this loop it asks me weather I'm sure to do this or not for every single item.

How can I bypass this approval in my `foreach` statements in general?

```
Get-SPDeletedSite | ForEach-Object {Remove-SPDeletedSite -identity $_}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add -Confirm:$false after -Identity $_

This way you will not be asked to confirm the action

Comment: thanks for your response, it says that confirmation is canceled in the current loop, am I right ?

Comment: You will not be asked to confirm the deletion done in the loop yes